# Using bootstrap modalpopup in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, bootstrap-modal

I have a `Products` page which displays a list of products. When i click `Details` button, i want to show product details in a bootstrap modal popup.

[image]

I want to get one of the product detail but this code gets all products details.

[image]

how can i fix this query:

**.aspx code:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
     <td> <div class="btn-ud" ><a href="<%#Eval("ProductID") %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="btn btn-custom-3 btn-sm"/ >Details</a> </div> </td> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**modal popup code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<asp:Repeater ID="rpProductDetails" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<tbody>
<td height="100px"> <%#Eval("ProductDetails")%> </td>
<td height="100px">  <%#Eval("ProductDetails")%> </td>
</tbody>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>      
</div>
```

**c# code:**

```
DataTable dtProductsDetails = system.GetDataTable("Select ProductDetails,TechDetails,Standards, ApplicationArea from TBLPRODUCTS where ProductID = ProductID");
          if (dtProductsDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              rpProductDetails.DataSource = dtProductsDetails;
              rpProductDetails.DataBind();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery for this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#myModal2").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: i have problem with data. I want to get one of the product detail in popup. when i click one of the product detail button, all products details displaying in popup

Comment: For that, you have to fetch product details on `modal shown` method via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function openModal() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
    </script>
```

In your c# code add an event for linkbutton like

```
    protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop","openModal();", true);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur advice i try this code but all products details displaying in popup again..

Comment: what you want to show? you are fetching all the data from product table in your query. you should select only desired column from database while joining tables.

Comment: when i click **Details** link it should be display one of the product detail which i clicked on it. how can i fix this query? `Select ProductDetails,TechDetails from TBLPRODUCTS where ProductID = ProductID`

Comment: USe _Select Top 1 ProductDetails, TechDetails, from TBLPRODUCTS where ProductID = ProductID_. if you want to display single record.

Comment: no i dont want to display single record. i want to display which product details i clicked, it details should be display.

Comment: oh ye, you should use hidden id in your itemtemplate like- _<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnProductId" Value='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>' />_. and then find it in your c# like -HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField) e.Item.FindControl("hdnProductId"); and assign it to your query.

Comment: In your query fetch data on the basis of this _hdnProductId_. it will bring related data of clicked item and remove this <%#Eval("ProductID") %> in href. use href="#" instead.