# Binding event before bootstrap modal show

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple bootstrap modal

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    ...
    <div>
</div>
```

I have attached it with a button using data-toggle

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"> Toggle</button>
```

Now when the button is clicked the modal will show up. The modal body contains a div which needs to be prepopulated. I used below code to do the same

```
$('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    generate_modal_body();    
})
```

But above code is not working. Surprisingly, if I add click event on the button on modal, it can trigger the generate_modal_body().
I have checked similar questions here but could not find satisfactory answer.
Please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Please provide JS Fiddle for your case and `generate_modal_body` function

Comment: i have the same problem; [Using bootstrap modalpopup in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312965/using-bootstrap-modalpopup-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please attach the shown event of bootstrap modal in the document ready function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
       generate_modal_body();
    }) ;
 });
</script>
```

Comment: @Shkupjane: showing the modal is not the problem. I need to trigger a javascript function which will populate data in model body which should be triggered first. Since I am using data-target in the button, I don't have seperate jqeury event on button click. Is there any way to do this w/o using native jquery events?

Comment: @bestrahul21 which version of Twitter Bootstrap are you using

Comment: shown event is not working either. I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: @bestrahul21 I mean to say put a debugger inside $('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){ 
       generate_modal_body();
    }) ; and see is it hitting the debugger or not and also show how your generate_modal_body  looks like

Answer (score 22):

You must use the correct [modal event](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp):
[image]

Comment: thank you. I think this should marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

pls try this

```
function openModal() {
      $('#mymodal').modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: I think there was some problem with my other part of code, I had written model instead of modal in some of the classes in html code, not sure if that created the problem. Now I could get the event triggered with 'shown.bs.modal' as was intended. Thank you everybody for looking into this.